# Replicate the CNN arhitecture from a paper

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network

In the paper it says:

> We train our model using CNN with the number of filters 128, stride of
> 1, and kernel size of 3, 4, and 5. We then apply the ReLu activation
> function with Max Pooling to the out of this layer; the output of this
> layer is often called feature maps. The feature maps are flattened and
> pass through three Fully-Connected layers (FC) with dropout between
> each layer. The first two FC layers use ReLu activation function with
> 256 and 64 of outputs. The last FC layer uses Softmax activation
> function which provides the output as complex (1)
> or non-complex (0).

From what I understand, it looks like this:

```
 cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(4, 4), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same'),
      layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dropout(0.25),
      layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dropout(0.25),
      layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'),
      ])
```

But my epochs take a lot of time to run so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Where are you training the model? What is the batch size?

Comment: @ashutoshsingh on my mac. batch size 32

Comment: That probably explains why your training is slow. You should use a GPU. Checkout Google Colaboratory. You can set your Runtime Type to GPU or TPU in case you are using Tensorflow